# what files does apk add to it's res/layout folder?

Tags: android

I'm working on restoring xml files of an app from its apk file.
I've found that if the source code has `activity_*.xml` in its `res/layout` folder, there were be many xml files in `res/layout` folder like `abc_*.xml` besides `avitivity_*.xml` after I use `apktool` to get the decompile results.I'm wondering whether there is a regular pattern of the name of extra files(such as `abc_*.xml`).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any pattern for them unless you obfuscate the code. Those extra files you see in the `res` folders are most likely from the SDKs or the dependencies that you are using to build your apk.